# Plot3D + WhenEvent + NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, event-detection

Given:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=-x-By^2 \\ \dot{y}=Ax-y^3 \end{cases}$

where $x,y$ - variables;

$A=[2;4],B=[0.2;2]$ - positive parameters;

My task is to find the time $t_n$ of the first intersection of a variable with zero. I do this with code:

```
pars = {A = 2, B = 1}

{sol, points} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - B x[t]^2, y'[t] == A x[t] - y[t]^3,
      x[0] == y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, Sow[{t, x'[t]}]]}, {x, 
     y}, {t, 15}];

Plot[{Evaluate[x'[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point @@ points}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200]

tn = points[[1, 1]][[1]]
```

How to build surfaces $t_n(A,B)$ for the specified range of parameters A and B?

Comment: Your code is not consistent with the equations shown, i.e., `x'[t] == -y[t] - B x[t]^2` versus `x'[t] == -x[t] - B y[t]^2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
tn[A_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] :=  
Block[{X},X = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -y[t] - B x[t]^2, y'[t] == A x[t] - y[t]^3, x[0] == y[0] == 1, 
WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, x,{t,15}];
X["Domain"][[1, 2]] (*returns time of WhenEvent*)
]
```

plot `tn[A,B]`

```
Plot3D[tn[A, B], {A, 2, 4}, {B, .2, 2},AxesLabel -> {A, B, tn}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ! This is a good option ! Tell me please, how can the $Plot$ be get from the surface now ? For example $t_n,A$ or $t_n,B$

Comment: You mean lines `A,B=constant`? Try `Plot[tn[A,1], {A, 2, 4}]`

Comment: Yes, I meant it. If I understand correctly, does this work with a lot of parameters as well?

Comment: Probably yes, I think.

Comment: http://drive.ispu.ru/elib/lebedev/16_files/image008.gif Another small clarification on the work of the WhenEvent with the method you proposed. Please take a look at the graph. How to calculate the time $t_p$? This is the time after which the trajectory of the state variable does not leave a certain zone $±\Delta$ around the steady state.

Comment: Seems to be a new question... I don't think that WhenEvent is able to  solve this task "looking in th future". You have to check after the simulation is completed.

Comment: Understood. I'll think about it. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Fine, you're welcome!

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253201/linearization-of-the-ode-system-problems